# show updated entity value in core data

Tags: ios, swift

in core data I have one entity **Products** and my attributes are **name** and **price**
in my main view controller I am fetching all the data from my core data using **nsfetchedresultcontroller** and showing the data in table view
when I tap on any of the cell I go to detail view to show detail of the product that is name and price using below,
in the detail view controller I have a variable selectedProduct

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let dvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "svc") as? SecondViewController{
            dvc.selectedProduct = frc.object(at: indexPath)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

in the detail view controller I can update the data of the product, meaning I can change the name or price of the product and save it using

```
selectedProduct.setValue("newName", forKey: "name")
```

lets say when I come to detail view it has two textfield one is showing name and the other is showing price, when I click on any of two textfield and change the value in it and press return button on keyboard which saves the value in the core data, how can I show updated value here after updating the value of **selectedProduct**

Comment: Actually in the same way you *show detail of the product* after presenting the controller.

Comment: but since selectedProduct value is assigned from main view controller so it is not going to show us updated value unless we go back to previous vc and comeback

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the context after updating the values.

```
do {
  try context.save()
} catch let err {
  print("Could not save.", err)
}
```

Comment: that I know the problem is how do I change the value in selectedProduct after contextdidsave